# How to adjusting p-values from results of trend analysis on water quality data

Tags: multiple-comparisons, trend, false-discovery-rate

I have results from Mann Kendall test for trends at 100 sample locations for 5 different analytes at each location (i.e., 500 p-values).  If I had the trend results from 500 sample locations for 1 analyte, I know that I could control the false detection rate (FDR) by adjusting the p-value using the Bonferroni or Benjamini-Hockberg methods, for example.

Given my trend results are for 5 different analytes, I believe, but I am not sure, that I should adjust the p-values associated with each analyte separately (e.g., adjust the p-values for the 100 sample locations for each analyte separately, giving 100 adjusted p-values for each analyte), rather than combining all the p-values (100 x 5 = 500) and adjusting the combined p-values.

Is my intuition correct?

Comment: Often a set of analytes reflects a mixture of highly correlated substances, so one would expect the tests at a single location not to be independent.  Standard methods of multi-comparisons correction would be overly severe.  You can assess this by evaluating the correlations: you have a lot of data to do that.  Whether the results are correlated across locations depends on those locations and the nature of the system you are measuring. E.g., points along a stream might yield large positive correlations, but widely spaced meteorological stations might not.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do expected the results to be correlated both at individual sites and between sites, as these are groundwater analyses collected around a know source of contamination.

Comment: One thing worth considering is whether you really need to make 500 separate trend determinations.  Often the larger questions are relatively few, such as is the total mass of dissolved contaminants increasing? Is the volume of the plume increasing? Is the plume front advancing at locations of concern? Is there evidence of natural attenuation?  *Etc., etc.* The problem with correcting for many multiple comparisons without doing detailed, careful modeling is that it can become almost impossible to detect anything, which renders the whole monitoring system almost useless.

Comment: BTW, I see you created two accounts in quick succession.  Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to combine them: that will help you manage your posts.

Comment: All excellent points.  Thanks